# what is the recommended way to create the terraform configuration from scratch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I think I am stuck on the error of the Terraform configuration for AWS RDS Aurora. I am following https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html but I still got error on `Error creating DB Instance: InvalidParameterCombination: Standalone DB Instances are not supported for the specified engine`

My question is what is the recommended way to create the terraform configuration from scratch?

This is my terraform config file

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "test" {
    identifier                = "test"
    allocated_storage         = 1
    storage_type              = "aurora"
    engine                    = "aurora"
    engine_version            = "5.6.10a"
    instance_class            = "db.t2.small"
    name                      = "testdb"
    username                  = "testadmin"
    password                  = "xxxxx"
    port                      = 3306
    publicly_accessible       = false
    availability_zone         = "us-east-2a"
    security_group_names      = []
    vpc_security_group_ids    = ["sg-xxxxx"]
    db_subnet_group_name      = "default-vpc-xxxxx"
    parameter_group_name      = "default.aurora5.6"
    multi_az                  = false
    backup_retention_period   = 1
    #backup_window             = "08:48-09:18"
    #maintenance_window        = "sun:08:56-sun:09:26"
    final_snapshot_identifier = "test-final"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AWS' Aurora uses a different API to the normal database instance calls that standard MySQL, Postgresql, etc use and instead uses the database cluster calls.

In Terraform this maps to the [`aws_rds_cluster`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/rds_cluster.html) and [`aws_rds_cluster_instance`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/rds_cluster_instance.html) resources instead of the [`aws_db_instance`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html) resource.

As such you need to use something like this:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster_instance" "cluster_instances" {
  count              = 1
  identifier         = "aurora-cluster-demo-${count.index}"
  cluster_identifier = "${aws_rds_cluster.default.id}"
  instance_class     = "db.t2.small"
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "default" {
  cluster_identifier = "aurora-cluster-demo"
  availability_zones = ["us-west-2a", "us-west-2b", "us-west-2c"]
  database_name      = "mydb"
  master_username    = "foo"
  master_password    = "barbut8chars"
}
```